# My bootstrap buttons are not showing the gradient or border and all gray

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

im new using bootstrap 3, but i've noticed a problem with my button rendering, they are showing like this:

[image: my buttons]
and i want them to show like this, the style i've found in all pages (this is a button group but im talking about the background color and style) mines are all gray...
[image]

i have this css added in this order, have changed them but no difference:

```
 ../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
 ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

the code of my buttons is:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini" type="submit" name="ver_rol" value=<?php echo $rol['rol_id']; ?>><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-mini" type="submit" name="editar_rol" value=<?php echo $rol['rol_id']; ?>><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-mini" type="submit" name="eliminar_rol" value=<?php echo $rol['rol_id']; ?>><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
```

please any help =(

Comment: Check your classes on the buttons.  I'm pretty sure Bootstrap 3 does not use btn-mini.  [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

Comment: Did you try adding `btn-*` fill the asterisk(*) with one of the various predefined words. Ex: `btn-warning` http://jacobrask.github.io/styledocco/styledocco/examples/bootstrap/docs/buttons.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 buttons are now 'flat', but you can use this theme to get the Bootstrap 2.x look: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Example: http://bootply.com/85619

Also, `btn-mini` is now `btn-xs` in Bootstrap 3.